# My flashplugin-nonfree (on Debian Stretch) is outdated... what to do?

Tags: debian, upgrade, adobe-flash

I use the version of Iceweasel on Debian Stretch GNU/Linux on an x86_64 machine. Sadly, I need to use Adobe's abominable Flash technology.

I know that the way you install the Flash plugin on Debian is using the flashplugin-nonfree package, after making setting the appropriate APT source settings. Well, I have, and it's installed and up-to-date - as far as the package goes, but, woe is me, when I open sites with Flash in Firefox it tells me that my Flash player is out-of-date!

So, first question:

- Is this my fault somehow (e.g. misconfiguration or what not), or is it just that the Stretch package maintainers haven't updated their version?

And then:

- Should I manually install the up-to-date plugin from adobe.com, or is there some other Debian-ish alternative?
- If the answer to the previous question is "yes", then - should I just overwrite `/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so` with the downloaded version, and overwrite the local settings, like Adobe's .tar.gz's README suggests, or should I do something else and Debian-specific?

Comment: What browser are you using? I use `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` with Chromium.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Iceweasel, see edit. But thanks.

Comment: Maybe check for alternatives with Iceweasel. Though perhaps there aren't any.

Comment: Or give https://wiki.debian.org/Freshplayerplugin a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the Flash plugin using

```
sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree
```

which is provided by `flashplugin-nonfree`.

Alternatively you can use Chrome's Flash plugin in Iceweasel using the `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` package (and `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`).

Comment: Stephen, either great minds think alike, or you swiped my research. :-)

Comment: @FaheemMitha I know, I saw your comment after I finished researching my edit!